# Using distinct to remove duplicates

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a class

```
class ShipmentsComparer : IEqualityComparer<Routes>
    {
        public bool Equals(Routes route1, Routes route2) =>
           route1.DockCode == route2.DockCode
           && route1.CarrierArrival == route2.CarrierArrival;

        public int GetHashCode(Routes obj) =>
        obj.DockCode.GetHashCode() ^ (obj.CarrierArrival.GetHashCode() * 13);
    }
```

and a IEnumerable

```
public IEnumerable <Shipments> Shipments
        {
            get
            {
                Debug.Print("Initiated");
                
                foreach (var item in Loads)
                {
                    if (item.ShipTo.Contains(" "))
                    {

                        foreach (var item2 in Routes.Where(d => d.DockCode == item.ShipTo.Substring(0, item.ShipTo.IndexOf(" ")) && d.CarrierDeparture.TimeOfDay == item.ShipTime.TimeOfDay).Distinct(new ShipmentsComparer()))
                        {
                                yield return new Shipments() { Arrival = item2.CarrierArrival, Departure = item2.CarrierDeparture, Issuer = item.Customer, Destination = item.ShipTo, LoadType = item.LoadType };
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

to remove duplicate values but I am still getting duplicates in my item source shown here:

[image: example]

How would I get this to only show one of each carrier arrival time?

Comment: please show the  implementation of `ShipmentsComparer`

Comment: The values of `CarrierArrival` (asumming it's `DateTime`) could be different (by up to several seconds). Can you prove there are really duplicates? The second red line is duplicate of what?

Comment: I think it's just because you go over Loads multiple times, meaning you iterate over Routes multiple times, meaning its possible to add items more than once even if you sample from a set that has no duplicates.

Comment: @mm8 I just tried that and still end up having that duplicate line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are getting duplicates because you are "distincting" only the inner loop result. You need either to use `Distinct` on calling side - `Shipmetns.Distinct(new ShipmentsComparer())` or if you want to to filter them in the property you can use `HashSet`:

```
class ActuallyShipmentsComparer : IEqualityComparer<Shipments>
{
   //your logic
}

    public IEnumerable <Shipments> Shipments
    {
        get
        {
            Debug.Print("Initiated");
            var hash = new HashSet<Shipments>(new ActuallyShipmentsComparer());               
            foreach (var item in Loads)
            {
                if (item.ShipTo.Contains(" "))
                {
                    foreach (var item2 in Routes.Where(d => d.DockCode == item.ShipTo.Substring(0, item.ShipTo.IndexOf(" ")) && d.CarrierDeparture.TimeOfDay == item.ShipTime.TimeOfDay).Distinct(new ShipmentsComparer()))
                    {
                            var shipments = new Shipments { Arrival = item2.CarrierArrival, Departure = item2.CarrierDeparture, Issuer = item.Customer, Destination = item.ShipTo, LoadType = item.LoadType };
                            if(hash.Add(shipments))
                            {
                                yield return shipments;
                            }
                         
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Or try the same with `Routes` if they are enough to determine shipments equality:

```
    public IEnumerable<Shipments> Shipments
    {
        get
        {
            Debug.Print("Initiated");
            var hash = new HashSet<Routes>(new ShipmentsComparer()); // rename ShipmentsComparer cause it is actually RoutesComparer             
            foreach (var item in Loads)
            {
                if (item.ShipTo.Contains(" "))
                {
                    foreach (var item2 in Routes.Where(d => d.DockCode == item.ShipTo.Substring(0, item.ShipTo.IndexOf(" ")) && d.CarrierDeparture.TimeOfDay == item.ShipTime.TimeOfDay))
                    {
                        if(hash.Add(item2))
                        {
                            yield return new Shipments { Arrival = item2.CarrierArrival, Departure = item2.CarrierDeparture, Issuer = item.Customer, Destination = item.ShipTo, LoadType = item.LoadType };
                        }                             
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i've never used a hashset before, I am getting this issue when using your bottom code: https://prnt.sc/tdh3gs the fix it wants me to do is `hash.Add(Routes)(Shipments))` which doesn't work either.

Comment: @SmackYouIn2.3 sorry, my bad, change it to `hash.Add(item2)` (fixed in my second snippet).

Comment: @SmackYouIn2.3 was glad to help!